# Prompting User Multiple Times for Numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I am fairly new to java. Here is what I am trying to do:

**Write a program that will calculate the perimeter and area of a rectangle.  Prompt the user to input the length and width. Calculate the area as length * width. Calculate the perimeter as 2* length + 2* width. Display the area and perimeter.**

Could someone please tell me what I need to do to get the program to work? I have referred back to some of my old codes that asked me to do a similar task, but it was not of any help. I know that the program would have to prompt the user to enter a number for the length, then again for the width. Can someone please help me with how to do it and how to take the number that the user enters to do the math to display a result?

Comment: Try something and post it here. Do not wait for us to solve your problem from the scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for this job is the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  Here's an example, from the documentation I linked to, of how to read an integer from the user input:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

Once you've done that once for the width and once for the length, then all you have to do is apply those formulas to it.

Comment: You are a good teacher Mr. TieTYT. I was thinking of giving him the code, however, he won't learn from that until I saw your answer. ;) +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Scanner` to grab input. So just make two variables representing the two inputs you need, and initialize each one using the scanner, while using `System.out.println()` to prompt the user for the inputs.

```
Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter length: ");
int length = getInput.nextInt();
System.out.println(""); //skip a line

System.out.print("Enter width: ");
int width = getInput.nextInt();
System.out.println(""); //skip a line
```

Answer (score 0):

A Scanner would do the trick, as this can scan the input that the user gives. A way to do this  would look like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Initialize the scanner to read user input
System.out.print("Enter Length: "); //Prompt user for length
int length = input.nextint(); //Make an integer that is equal to what the user's input is
System.out.print("\nEnter Width: "); //Prompt user for width
int width = input.nextInt();
```

To calculate the perimeter, based on what the user selects, add this after the previous code:

```
int perimeter = (width * 2) + (length * 2);
System.out.print("The perimeter is: " + perimeter);
```

To calculate the area, add this after the first piece of code:

```
int area = width * length;
System.out.print("The area is: " + area);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ which is the official tutorial on IO. It has examples, etc.